# AngularJS - show timeout message for POST request after certain time

Tags: angularjs, post

I am trying below code to display timeout message after certain time for the POST request

```
$scope.timeout = false;  
$scope.testAPICall = function(){

  $http({
    url: 'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
    method: "POST",
    data: postData
  })
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.timeout = true;
    $scope.persons = data; 
   })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
  });
}  

$timeout(testAPICall,1000) //for testing I kept 1000ms
if(!timeoutTest){
  alert("Timeout!!!");
}
```

Problem is that I am trying on working API that gives response time in 135ms and for added functionality, I am adding timeout message for long running requests

Comment: Did you say the API gives you a response time of 135px (pixels?!)

Comment: sorry typo ..it is 135ms

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$q` provider to help with this:

```
$scope.testApiCall = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $timeout(function() {
    deferred.reject("Timed out!");
  }, 1000);

  $http({
    url: 'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
    method: "POST",
    data: postData
  })
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
   })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.reject(status);
  });

  return deferred.promise;

};

//Call function like this

$scope.testApiCall().then(function(data) {
  $scope.persons = data.persons;
})
.catch(function(status) {
  $scope.status = status;
});
```

If the time limit is reached, the promise will be rejected, otherwise it will work as normal.